# How to use doorkeeper with an android client?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

I'm building an application which consists of a mobile client (Android native app) that will connect to my rails application. I need a way for users to signin and signup to my rails app using the android app. So I installed doorkeeper and devise gems on my rails app and followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Authorization-Code-Flow) to see how things work. As you can see in the [authorization code flow page](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Authorization-Code-Flow) there are multiple steps such as registering the client, requesting authorization, requesting the access token.
My question is how do I perform all these steps from my android app. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For registration (sign up) you can create a method in the user controller that does just that. Or you can customise Devise's sign_up page to look better in a mobile view and do the registration in a webview in the app.

As for Doorkeeper, either follow the usual flow as linked by you or give it a simpler approach. What I did was to

1. [activate the refresh token](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Enable-Refresh-Token-Credentials) - this will allow a user to get his access token and his refresh token, token used to regenerate the access token once it expires. This way you don't retain the user's login registration on your app, just the tokens.
2. white label some apps in config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb by using the **[skip_authorization](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Skipping-application-authorization)** to allow auto authorisation of some particular apps. You can allow auto authorisation to all the apps but I'd recommend you just whitelist some of them:

   ```
   skip_authorization do |client|
     whitelisted_apps = ['app1_id', 'app2_id']
     whitelisted_apps.include? client.application.uid
   end
   ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually my question was how do I do the oauth flow on android.After searching around I found this scribe-java library [link](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java). But I still haven't figured out how to put these three things together. Meaning devise, doorkeeper and scribe.

Comment: I understand. I actually used the mentioned workflow with a mobile app. The iOS programmer ditched the 3rd party library in favor of a simple REST API call that stored the access token and the refresh token locally. After that, the only thing he did was to use the refresh token to get a new pair of access + refresh token whenever he encountered a 401 HTTP code from the server. Where exactly did you get stuck so I can provide a more on topic help?

Comment: I actually didn't get how oauth worked. After going through the official doc I realized I need to use the password grant flow. But there seems to be another problem coming up. I uncomented `use_refresh_token` in my doorkeeper.rb file. so now my first request to the api is successful but when i fire another request it responds with 401 unauthorized. Do I have to use refresh token to get a new access token for every request?

Comment: No, the access token is used for authentication and the refresh token is used to get a new token once the one you used has expired. My guess is you're either using your refresh token instead of your access token to authenticate or the expiration time is way too short.